# retain value after page refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, refresh

I am using a button control("validation button") in c#.
I define some global variable in my project.
when I clicked the button some form validation happens and an another button("save button") gets visible.
 the problem is when i click the validation button, the current page refreshes and the global variable doesn't contain the values. it shows null.
how cal i maintain the value in global variable even after page refresh.

Answer (score 2):

This is asp.net, correct?
Store this value in session `Session["MyVariable"] = value` and read it from session `value = Session["MyVaraible"]`
There other alternatives, ViewState, Application or even use a static variable but using session will be simple enough for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use Session State http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87069683(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Its not clear what do you mean by *global variable*. Assuming that its page level (instance) variable, your best bet will be to use view-state. Define a view-state backed property such as

```
private int MyVar
{
  get
  {
     var value = ViewState["MyVar"];
     return null != value ? (int)value: 0;
  }
  set
  {
    ViewState["MyVar"] = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: ViewState is deleted on page refresh, so it cannot be used for such purpose. SessionState also cannot be used because all pages opened in the same browser will use the run within the same Session, so it also cannot be used. :-\

Comment: @dmitry_bond, OP was talking about page refresh on button click (a post-back scenario), hence the relevance of view-state.

Answer (score 0):

Second way: use client events of button without PostBack (set button AutoPostback property to false) to validate your form. After that use server handler of second button to post form fields values...

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean that:you declared some variables `globally` , but normally those variables will lost their values at the end of the page cycle.

if you want to maintain the variables values after post back you can use `static variables`,but **take care they will be shared between all users**.the good choice using `session variables`.